# What should I do about a gap between a kitchen backsplash and the cupboards?

Tags: kitchens, tile, backsplash

Theres a small gap between the backsplash and cupboards,  the gap is too small to cut strips of backsplash to Make it look normal.  I have run out of ideas.  Any of you pros got any ideas?

[image: backsplash]

Comment: pics and more details of the materials used would help but as a quick fix you can try wearing taller heels. If you can't see it, it's not broken. :)

Comment: Lol, unfortunately I am a guy that is not an option :).  The materials used are mosaic tile backsplash made of glass and stainless steel. If I could figure out how to attach a picture that would also help

Comment: https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/320xq90/r/537/iceu0Z.jpg

Comment: Added a picture ^^

Comment: the tile isn't installed yet? How big is the gap? Can you cut the tiles?

Comment: Not all of it, yet.

Comment: If i fill it with grout the it will eventually crack and fall out

Comment: Gap is 3/8's of an inch

Comment: When the tile is raised to mimic the rest of the joints, the gap will be a 1/4" or less. No, the SANDED grout you choose to use will not fall out. I believe if you simply grout everything, the joint at the top will blend a lot more than you may realize. As a mention, tape the edge of the cabinet before you start, it may scratch the finish. I would not use silicone at the bottom corner of this job. Major grout companies will have a sanded caulk to match the grout, use that instead. Silicone will have a distracting shine to it.

Comment: You could try using a wet saw to cut your tiles in half lengthwise, and in half again if that's possible.

Answer (score 5):

The grout lines in the mosaic tile look like 1/8" is that right?

If that's the case you need to space the tiles up off the counter using 1/8" spacers. They shouldn't be directly on the counter as shown in your picture where you're just holding it. When grouting don't grout that area. Use a silicon caulk that matches your grout instead.

That leaves 1/4"  grout line between the top of the tile and the bottom of the cupboard which isn't ideal but shouldn't really be noticeable at that spot. That covers the 3/8" gap.

Or you can split the difference and do a 3/16" on top and bottom. May even want to try a black caulk for the top so you don't notice it against the black cabinets.

Answer (score 3):

First the tile would not be installed right on top of the counter.  You would need the same grout gap as the tile has guessing 1/8" - 1/16" would be the closest.  So your gap isn't even that big.

I would not rip this tile with a saw.  I have used this before and it doesn't rip or cut well.

If it were my house I would go to the tile store and find a mosaic that comes in very thin strips and use it along the top or bottom or both.  It is quite likely you only need a sheet or two to make this happen it it will keep you from having to make tons of hard cuts.

Good tiling is more about math/planning than cutting.